# VBA Excel running macro based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am attempting to automate an error report. I am sending an email with the results if one of the 4 conditions are true. Here is the code so far:

```
Sub EmailFRSErrors()
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Set SrchRng = Range("A2:A5000")

For Each cel In SrchRng
 If InStr(1, cel.Value, "22") > 0 Or InStr(1, cel.Value, "26") > 0 Or InStr (1, cel.Value, "44") > 0 Or InStr(1, cel.Value, "46") > 0 Then
 OpenOutlookEmail
End If
Next
End Sub
```

My issue is, if there are more than two errors it runs the OpenOutlookEmail macro once for each error. I want it to run once whether there is 1 error or 10. The macro it is running is going to copy the range and paste all the errors into outlook and send them off. I only need 1 email sent with all errors.

Thanks!

Comment: put in `Exit Sub` before the `End If`

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment above you will just need to add the `Exit Sub` to your `If` statement like this:

```
Sub EmailFRSErrors()
    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
    Set SrchRng = Range("A2:A5000")

    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "22") > 0 Or InStr(1, cel.Value, "26") > 0 Or InStr (1, cel.Value, "44") > 0 Or InStr(1, cel.Value, "46") > 0 Then
            OpenOutlookEmail
            Exit Sub 'This will exit the sub after sending only one email instead of continuing and potentially sending multiple
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```